# Is "be made upon" a phrase?

Tags: phrases

"Any tender of documents or money hereunder may be made upon Vendor or Purchaser."

I never seen the phrase "be made upon". I tried to search for it online but found nothing useful.
What does "be made upon" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a common expression, and can be considered "contractese": A dialect used for writing legal documents'

"To make a tender" means to formally present (money or legal documents), and "hereunder" refers to the paragraphs below this one.  These paragraphs (presumably) specify processes by which the vendor and purchaser can exchange money or legal documents.

So to "make a tender of a document upon someone" would mean "to formally present the document" and the implication of "upon" is that that the person being offered the document cannot refuse to accept it. And,  moreover, these rules apply equally to the vendor and purchaser.